# Err: Couldn't find the module "/vercel/path0/node_modules/@mui/material/node/Box/index.js#" in React Client Manifest

Tags: reactjs, next.js, material-ui, bundler, modulenotfounderror

```
Err: Couldn't find the module "/vercel/path0/node_modules/@mui/material/node/Box/index.js#" in React Client Manifest. This is probably a bug in the React Server Components bundler.
```

Getting this issue while local build too, on `npm run build`

```
- "next": "^13.5.1",
- "@emotion/react": "^11.11.1",
- "@emotion/styled": "^11.11.0",
- "@mui/icons-material": "^5.14.9",
- "@mui/material": "^5.14.10",
```

I have tried to upgrade MUI version, but it still persists